# How does type() function infers type

Tags: python, inheritance, types

Im trying to compare types of two objects by using `isinstance(obj1, type(obj2))`.

However, im not really sure how type infers the typing of an object - or whether theres a chance that the type returned is of an ancestor class.

Comment: `obj2` was created by a call to *some class*, like `obj2 = Foobar()`. `type` returns *that* class object…

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1549801/20163209) answer your question? `isinstance` checks for inheritance whereas `type` gives you just the type of the object back

Comment: @deceze what if obj2 was obtained as a function parameter with a typing of an ancestor class, would it matter?

Comment: It returns the actual constructor class that constructed the object. How it was passed where is irrelevant and not even data that is attached to the object in any way.

Comment: "However, im not really sure how type infers the typing of an object" It doesn't infer it, it retrieves the type directly from the object (all objects have a reference to their type).

Comment: @snufsan "what if obj2 was obtained as a function parameter with a typing of an ancestor class, would it matter? " do you mean a *type hint*? No that doesn't matter. Type hints are *hints*. Python is a dynamically typed language, parameters *don't have types* and you can pass any object to any parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Given three classes `A`, `B`, `C`. Class `B` is subclass of `A` and class `C` is subclass of `B`.

```py
class A:
    pass

class B(A):
    pass

class C(B):
    pass
```

Using `type` on an object is the same thing as calling `obj.__class__`. This returns the class to which an instance belongs.

`isinstance` however also checks for **subclasses**. So your call `isinstance(obj1, type(obj2))` depends on if the two objects are related.

```py
>>> a = A()
>>> b = B()
>>> c = C()
>>> type(c) == type(b)
False
>>> isinstance(c, type(b))
True
```

Instance `c` is of type `<class '__main__.C'>` and `b` is of type `<class '__main__.B'>`. So the comparison using `type` evaluates to `False`.

A more elaborate example of your approach and using the class directly:

```py
>>> isinstance(c, type(b))  # as C is subclass of B
True
>>> isinstance(c, B)  # using the class directly
True
>>> isinstance(b, type(c))  # as b is of parent class B
False
>>> isinstance(b, C)  # C is subclass of B, thus b is not an instance of C
False
>>> isinstance(c, type(a))  # C is subclass of B which is subclass of A
True
```

Comment: I used `isinstance(obj1, CLS) and isinstance(obj2, CLS)` however its not elegant when CLS is not known prior

Comment: Why wouldn't you know the class prior? In what context do you use the `isinstance` check?

Comment: It can have one of few types, where all are subclasses of the same class

Comment: If they are all subclasses of the same parent class, they all have all the functionalities of that parent class. If however, you need something specific only possible in one of the subclasses, you check again with `isinstance(obj, subclass)`